# Finding Data Engineering tool for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am looking for a data engineering tool for ArcGIS Pro 2.6.2.

However, I cannot find it in the data or analysis, where I think it should be.

How can I reach it?

Comment: You need to upgrade your version of arcpro to at least 2.8. if you look at the top of most [help pages](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/data-engineering/what-is-data-engineering.htm) it tells you which version the topic is suitable for.

Answer (score 1):

Data Engineering in ArcGIS Pro is available with version 2.8x.

Upgrade the application to get the data engineering functionality.

https://geospatialtraining.com/arcgis-pro-2-8-data-engineering-tutorial/